# Limiting Search and Replace to Category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I wish to find and replace a certain keyword across a major site.

I would normally use something like

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts 
   SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'Item to replace here', 'Replacement text here');
```

However, I don't want the update to be across the entire site, I wish to limit it to only one category.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** To be more precise the query should look

```sql
UPDATE wp_term_relationships r JOIN wp_posts p 
    ON r.object_id = p.id JOIN wp_terms t
    ON r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x
    ON r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id
   SET p.post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'Item to replace here', 'Replacement text here')
 WHERE t.name = 'My Category'
   AND x.taxonomy = 'category'
   AND x.parent = 0 -- top level category
```

**Note:** before you update anything:

1) you can check what posts will be affected by issuing

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM wp_term_relationships r JOIN wp_posts p 
    ON r.object_id = p.id JOIN wp_terms t
    ON r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x
    ON r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id
 WHERE t.name = 'My Category'
   AND x.taxonomy = 'category'
   AND x.parent = 0  -- top level category
```

2) make sure you have a solid **backup** of your wordpress database.

Comment: Peter, how would this change if the Category is a Sub-category instead?

I tried running this, but once the query runs it just shows details for one category above it.

Comment: @Shakey Do you by any chance have more than one subcategory with the same name but different parent categories?

Comment: Not at all. I thought something along those lines too, but there is no other sub-category with the same name at all.

Comment: Peter, Still the same thing. It shows the correct category taxonomy ID, the correct name and slug. But the post it retrieves are of the previous category. So Sub-category 46 has 500 posts and subcategory 47 has 20 posts. If I query subcategory 47 - It returns 500 rows with all posts of sub-category 47. If that makes sense.